# makefile does not reach "clean" to delete .o files

Tags: makefile

```
CXX=clang++ $(CXXFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS=-O2
OFILES=a.o b.o c.o

.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp

main: $(OFILES)
    $(CXX) $(OFILES)

clean: rm -f *.o *~ 

a.o: a.cpp a.h
b.o: b.cpp b.h
c.o: c.cpp
```

The .o files are not being deleted. When I try putting an @echo before the rm, it seems like that doesn't happen either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is now, the `clean` target *depends* on the "files" `rm`, `-f`, `*.o` and `*~`. So it will only be run if those "files" have been modified.

The line

```
clean: rm -f *.o *~
```

should be the *two* lines

```
clean:
    rm -f *.o *~
```

---

A common way to write makefiles is something like this:

```
# Variables
VARIABLE1=value1
VARIABLE2=value2
# etc...

# Targets
# The first target is the "default" target when `make` is invoked
# without any specific target
default: some_other_target

# Other targets...
```

In your case, if you want the "default" target to be `clean` then if you use the template given above, you make `default` depend on the `clean` target:

```
default: clean
```

Comment: so how would i get it to delete them? when i do "make", a.o, b.o, and c.o appear in the directory. i am trying to get rid of these.

Comment: @TidusSmith Read my whole answer, it has the solution.

Comment: was using two lines supposed to make it work? the .o files are still not being removed.

Comment: @TidusSmith And there is no other error message? Remember that makefiles are sensitive when it comes to whitespace, it *must* tabs used, not space, to indent the lines with the commands.

Comment: my apologies. "make clean" does work. i am trying to just use "make" and have it automatically delete the files without having to do "make clean" after.

Comment: @TidusSmith By default, `make` without specifying any target picks the *first* target in the makefile.

Comment: i see. so i would just put the rm under the first target. clearly, i'm new to using make files. thank you for your help!

Comment: @TidusSmith If you want `clean` to be the default target, it should the first target. Also updated my answer with some more information.

Answer (score 1):

@Tidus Smith. If you want to remove the objects after compile, you can add the rm command after the $(CC).

```
main: $(OFILES)
    $(CXX) $(OFILES)
    rm -f *.o *~
```

This ensures that after the compilation is done all the .o files and the *~ files are removed.